# Using SemaphoreSlim for tasks with return type

Tags: c#, .net, parallel-processing, task-parallel-library, tpl-dataflow

I am trying to create a producer/consumer TPL dataflow process. As part of it, I will be creating multiple producer tasks for different id range which will generate the data records for processing. So I am planning to throttle the number of threads that will connect to database to get the data and be active at same time.

However, the method which extracts data and sends it to `BufferBlock` has a return type so that I can get the count of records extracted. So I am unable to figure out where to call the Release method from the `SemaphoreSlim` class, but still be able to get a return value? Below is the sample code that I am using. Can someone please suggest any work around for this?

```
private Task<KeyRange>[] DataExtractProducer(ITargetBlock<DataRow[]> targetBuffer, ExtractQueryConfiguration QueryConf)
{
    CancellationToken cancelToken = cancelTokenSrc.Token;
    var tasks = new List<Task<KeyRange>>();
    int taskCount = 0;
    int maxThreads = QueryConf.MaxThreadsLimit > 0 ? QueryConf.MaxThreadsLimit : DataExtConstants.DefaultMaxThreads;

    using (SemaphoreSlim concurrency = new SemaphoreSlim(maxThreads))
    {
        foreach (KeyRange range in keyRangeList)
        {
            concurrency.WaitAsync();

            var task = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Console.WriteLine(MsgConstants.StartKeyRangeExtract, QueryConf.KeyColumn, range.StartValue, range.EndValue);
                //concurrency.Release();
                return GetDataTask(targetBuffer, range, QueryConf.ExtractQuery);
            }, cancelToken);

            tasks.Add(task);
            taskCount++;
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(MsgConstants.TaskCountMessage, taskCount);

    return tasks.ToArray<Task<KeyRange>>();
}
```

Edit: I tried this variant also. But this does not seem to work. I tried with limit of 20. But I see more than 50 DB connections going out. Eventually, I am hitting high memory consumption because of the unthrottled connections.

```
using (SemaphoreSlim concurrency = new SemaphoreSlim(maxThreads))
{
    foreach (KeyRange range in keyRangeList)
    {
        concurrency.WaitAsync();
    
        var task = Task.Run(() =>
        {
            Console.WriteLine(MsgConstants.StartKeyRangeExtract, QueryConf.KeyColumn, range.StartValue, range.EndValue);
            var temptask = await GetDataTask(targetBuffer, range, QueryConf.ExtractQuery);
            concurrency.Release();
            return temptask;
        }, cancelToken);

        tasks.Add(task);
        taskCount++;
    }
}
```

Comment: First you need to await `WaitAsync` otherwise your Semaphore doesn’t serve any function. Second, why is GetDataTask wrapped in another task? You could just write `var task = GetDataTask(…);` without wasting a threadpool thread. Finally, if you want a (bounded) producer consumer collection you should use a [BlockingCollection](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd267312(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of reimplementing it yourself.

Comment: You could drop the `Semaphore` and just use dataflow all the way, but it's not clear what you're really going for. Specifically how is the return value from this used?

Comment: If you use TPL data flow anyway, you should just use its inbuilt async producer consumer collections, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225361/is-there-anything-like-asynchronous-blockingcollectiont

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something but why not release after `GetDataTask` and then `return`?

Comment: I am using TPL dataflow only. I am using BufferBlock with BoundedCapacity. This is just the producer part which will be multi-threaded. Eventually, i need to add transformation and action block with consumers also. The producer will extract data from database. Each task will do this for an id range and perform a SendAsync to the Bufferblock within the GetDataTask method. Because of the SendAsync call, I had to wrap that method as a async Task.

Comment: The return value is class that has expected record count and actual record count. If those dont match or lets say there is a timeout, I will need to add logic to reprocess it before calling the targetBuffer.Completed() method to indicate producer process was completed.

Comment: @JSteward, i have updated my question with your suggestion of releasing after GetDataTask. Though the code compiles and runs, it still suffers from the same problem as before. That is it still does not throttle the number of tasks. Essentially, I only want x number of instances of GetDataTask method running to limit the number of DB connections.

Comment: @askids Like I said at least await your lock, otherwise all tasks will run at the same time.

Comment: To elaborate on @ckuri you need to `await concurrency.WaitAsync();`

Comment: @JSteward and ckuri, thank you. That resolved the issue. I will post the final version in some time.

Comment: Still have an open issue. Now that Semaphore is working, do I still need to return a task array? Can I just return the List of KeyRange? Currently, though the parallel data extract tasks are being throttled, after the final extract, the task is still waiting. I have below code which waits for it to complete.

Task<Task<KeyRange>[]> task = DataExtractProducer(targetBuffer, MultiThreadedExtractQueryConf);
await Task.WhenAll(task);
await Task.WhenAll(task.Result);

Comment: @askids it may be best to ask a new question. A good [MCVE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that at least shows how this code is called and the methods you call would help to get a good answer. Right now I have to make a lot of guesses and assumptions that may not be true.

Comment: @JSteward thanks the suggestion. I will raise it as new question. For the time being, if you can just add await part as a separate comment, I will will accept it as answer as that was the original issue that I had posted and bring this to a logical end.

Comment: Are you aware that the TPL Dataflow has a [`MaxDegreeOfParallelism`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.executiondataflowblockoptions.maxdegreeofparallelism) option?