# Can BlockingCollection.GetConsumingEnumerable Deadlock

Tags: c#, async-await, ienumerable

Assuming I have an async builder method and I need to convert a collection of db models into a collection of UI models, I wrote the code below (simplified for example).

After reading [this medium article](https://medium.com/rubrikkgroup/understanding-async-avoiding-deadlocks-e41f8f2c6f5d), the code was refactoring to bubble ASYNC all the way up but I'd still like to know

1. will `collection.GetConsumingEnumerable()` block, leading to deadlocks, similar to `.Wait` or `.Result`
2. what is the preferred way to stream items in an async method

```cs
    public IEnumerable<GenericDevice> GetGenericDevices(SearchRequestModel srModel)
    {
        var collection = new BlockingCollection<GenericDevice>(new ConcurrentBag<GenericDevice>());
        Task.Run(() => QueueGenericDevices(collection, srModel));
    
        foreach (var genericDevice in collection.GetConsumingEnumerable())
        {
               yield return genericDevice;
        }
    }
    
    private async Task QueueGenericDevices(BlockingCollection<GenericDevice> collection, SearchRequestModel srModel)
    {
        var efDevices = _dbDeviceRepo.GetEfDevices(srModel);
    
        var tasks = efDevices
               .Select(async efDevice =>
               {
                     var genericDevice = await BuildGenericDevice(efDevice, srModel);
                     collection.Add(genericDevice);
               });
    
        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);
        collection.CompleteAdding();
    }
```

Comment: If you target .NET Core 3+, then it's possible to use async enumerators.

Comment: Related: [Is there anything like asynchronous BlockingCollection<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225361/is-there-anything-like-asynchronous-blockingcollectiont)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> will collection.GetConsumingEnumerable() block, leading to deadlocks, similar to .Wait or .Result

No. There are two parts to [the classic deadlock](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html):

1. A context that only allows one thread at a time (usually a UI `SynchronizationContext` or ASP.NET pre-Core `SynchronizationContext`).
2. Blocking on code that uses `await` (which [uses that context](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/02/async-and-await.html) in order to complete the `async` method).

`GetConsumingEnumerable` is a blocking call, but it's not blocking on asynchronous code, so there's no danger of the classic deadlock there. More generally, using a queue like this inserts a "barrier" of sorts between two pieces of code.

> what is the preferred way to stream items in an async method

Modern code should use `IAsyncEnumerable<T>`.

However, if you're not on that platform yet, you can use a queue as a "barrier". You wouldn't want to use `BlockingCollection<T>`, though, because it is designed for synchronous producers and synchronous consumers. For asynchronous producers/consumers, I'd recommend Channels.

Comment: Thanks Stephen, you've got a lot of great information on your blog.  When you get some time, I'd love to see a blog with your three examples: async enumerable, queue, and channels.

Comment: On the blocking collection note, I did indeed run into an issue of completing early.  I had to add `await Task.WhenAll(tasks);` to block until all adds were complete.  Is that the issue you are referring to?

Comment: @BrantleyBlanchard: No; I mean that `GetGenericDevices` is now a synchronous method that is (presumably) called on the UI thread. So a `foreach` over its enumerable will just block the UI. You can use Channels instead, where the consumption pattern includes `await`ing for more items to be available - that way, the UI can remain responsive.