# Is there Microsoft implemented thread safe collection with a similar working?

Tags: c#, multithreading, list, collections, thread-safety

I remember I saw a class with 2 exciting properties. I couldn't remember the class name but I think it was a collection, I'm not sure. The first property was named Read*word* and the second property was called Write*word*. Sadly I don't remember. Let me try to explain why these 2 properties exist. The idea was when a write happens we allow the already running "Reads" to finish but new ones will need to wait. See below how one would use this class.

```
var list = new ThreadSafeList();

// This is how we should read the collection.
using(var read = list.ReadLock)
{
 // If a write is happening we will wait until it finishes.
 await read.WaitAsync();

 // Do something with the list. If we are here in the execution no writing can happen, only reads.
}

// This is how we should change the collection.
using(var write = list.WriteLock)
{
 await write.WaitAsync();

 // Modify the collection, nobody reads it, so we are safe.
}
```

Do I remember right? Is there a collection that has similar properties? If not can somebody tell me how I should make a similar class is this an AutoResetEvent or a ManualResetEvent maybe a Sempahore? I don't know.

Comment: Probably related: [Is there anything like asynchronous BlockingCollection<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225361/is-there-anything-like-asynchronous-blockingcollectiont)

Comment: Could you be thinking of [`ReaderWriterLockSlim`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?view=net-6.0) ?

Comment: Not exactly a list (which doesn't really make sense in a thread-safe context anyway) but if you need a MS solution you can use [`BufferBlock<T>`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.tasks.dataflow.bufferblock-1) from the `System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow` NuGet package. [Here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-write-messages-to-and-read-messages-from-a-dataflow-block#writing-and-reading-asynchronously) is an example for async usage.

Comment: `Channel<T>` maybe? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.channels.channel-1?view=net-6.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> The idea was when a write happens we allow the already running "Reads" to finish but new ones will need to wait. See below how one would use this class.

Sounds like a reader/writer lock to me. Reader/writer locks can be used *with* collections, although the lock itself does not contain items.

There is a [synchronous reader/writer lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.readerwriterlockslim?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) in the BCL. There is no asynchronous version, though.

Usually, when people ask for a reader/writer lock, I ask them to carefully reflect whether they *really need it*. Just the fact that you have some code acting as a reader and other code acting as a writer does not imply you should have a reader/writer lock. RWLs are possibly one of the most misused synchronization primitives; a simple `lock` (or `SemaphoreSlim` for the asynchronous case) usually suffices just fine.

> Is there a collection that has similar properties?

There are certainly reader/writer *collections* available. These work by containing a number of items and permit different parts of code to produce or consume items. Hence the common name "producer/consumer" collections.

The one I would recommend these days is [System.Threading.Channels](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/dotnet/an-introduction-to-system-threading-channels/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058). [TPL Dataflow](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/dataflow-task-parallel-library?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058) is another option.

Note that you don't have to take any locks with Channels/Dataflow. Your producers just produce data items, and your consumers just consume them. All the locking is internal to these collections.

> If not can somebody tell me how I should make a similar class

If, after careful reflection, you really *do* want an asynchronous reader/writer lock, you can make one [like this](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/pfxteam/building-async-coordination-primitives-part-7-asyncreaderwriterlock/?WT.mc_id=DT-MVP-5000058).