# How to optimize producer-consumer scenario with maximum 1 minute latency requirement

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, architecture, producer-consumer

I have been struggling with a solution proposal for a long time, so I will be grateful for any advice.

My structure is very simple. I have moduleA which has a collection of ModuleB

- ModuleA

  - ModuleB (0)
  - ModuleB (1)
  - ModuleB (2)
  - ...
  - ModuleB (n < 50)

## Features:

- ModuleA can contain a maximum of 50 ModuleB.
- ModuleA receives all measured data via one stream. It depends on the situation, but approximately 50 to 200 values per second.
- ModuleA must distribute data to all ModuleB without affecting the speed of reading data from the stream.
- Each moduleB works independently, according to the customer's requirements, it does different calculations, sends notifications elsewhere, stores other data in the DB, etc. It means that not all data received in ModuleA is needed by each ModuleB.
- If ModuleB performs a calculation, sends data to another system or stores previously processed data in the DB, it is unable to receive incoming data. These data must wait, but at the same time, all data have a maximum of 1 minute for processing, if thelimit is exceeded, the data is invalid.

## My architecture:

**Stream:**
-> ModuleA -> ConcurrentStack.Push() -> EventWaitHandle**X**.Set()

**Separately running thread in ModuleA:**
-> EventWaitHandle**X**.WaitOne() -> ConcurrentStack.TryPeek() -> ModuleB -> ConcurrentStack.Push() -> EventWaitHandle**Y**.Set()

**Separately running thread in ModuleB:**
-> EventWaitHandle**Y**.WaitOne() -> ConcurrentStack.TryPeek() -> SemaphoreSlim.WaitAsync() -> add data to process

## Problems:

- A lot of threads
- Constantly pulled processor to 100% (45x ModuleB, 32GB ram, i9 3.6GHz processor)
- Very slow app
- dotnet-trace shows that the biggest problem is EventWaitHandle and ConcurrentStack.

## Questions:

- Any idea how to design it differently?
- Any idea how to reduce the load of EventWaitHandle and ConcurrentStack?
- Any idea if I could reasonably replace EventWaitHandle and ConcurrentStack?
- Any other ideas or observations?

**The application is more complex, this is just a very simplified view of the matter.**

thank you very much for any help or opinion

Comment: You might find this interesting: [Is there anything like asynchronous BlockingCollection<T>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21225361/is-there-anything-like-asynchronous-blockingcollectiont)

Comment: @TheodorZoulias Thank you very much, so far I managed to perform a couple of tests with Channel and it seems that only "Channel" is more effective than my ConcurrentStack + EventWaitHandle solution. I need to create some test applications to compare several options.